# Upgrading JSON Encode php 5.2

Tags: php, json

JSON encode for php 5.2 seems to be buggy. I need a way to upgrade it to php 5.3+ without changing my PHP version, is this possible? If so how?

Thanks

Found the problem - it was an encoding problem in the end with my string. Use:

iconv('Windows-1252', 'UTF-8', $string);

Jsonencode fails if your string is not properly encoded.

Comment: I don't believe its buggy but you always can use third party libraries like `Zend_Json` or many other.

Comment: Postage app is having problems with it.

Comment: OK, just trying to see how your problem can be solved. Stay vague if you don't want that... The answer is: no, you cannot upgrade just `json_encode`.

Comment: why can't you upgrade to php 5.3? (you are aware that 5.2 has been officially end-of-life and unsupported for the best part of two years already, right?)

Comment: also, if you're going to state that something appears to be buggy, perhaps offering some proof would help. If you show us some data that demonstrates the problem, we might be able to say "oh yes, that's a known issue, here's the way to deal with it". Without any kind of example, we can't offer any help other than to say "sorry, what you're asking for can't be done."

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what bugs your getting, but someong at php.net wrote a function for version before 5.2, maybe that will work for you, just give it a new name like "myjson"

See: [craig at craigfrancis dot co dot uk](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#107968)'s listing.